# Access elements inside a div outside of the current div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is probably a very easy approach, however I haven't been able to figure it out.

My approach is to get all `<img>` elements that have the "expanded-image" class that are within the "img-preview" of my current "entry".

This is my html:

```
<div class="entry">
 <div class="img-preview">
    <img>
    <img class="expanded-image" style="display:none;">
 </div>

 <div class="content">
    [..]
    [..]
    <span class="more-text"></span>
    [..]
    [..]
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JS I work with:

```
$('.content').each(function(event) {

  $(this).find('span.more-text').click(function(event) {

      // TODO 

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you don't need the `each()` at all as you can apply the `click()` event handler to all elements within a single selector.

To solve your issue you can use `closest()` to find the nearest parent `.entry` element to the clicked `.more-text`. From there you can `find()` all the `.expanded-image` elements. Try this:

```
$('.content span.more-text').click(function(event) {
    var $imgs = $(this).closest('.entry').find('.img-preview .expanded-image');
    // work with $imgs here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.content').each(function(event) {
  var $content = $(this);

  $(this).find('span.more-text').click(function(event) {

      $content.parent().find('.expanded-image'); // there you go

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o combination of `closest`, `prev` and `find`

```
$('span.more-text').click(function(event) {
     $(this).closest('.content').prev().find('.expanded-image');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to bubble up to find the parent given in the selector. Then from there you can navigate down to the required elements.

```
 $(this).closest('.entry').find('.img-preview .expanded-image');
```

Also as Ron has suggested you dont have to loop and then bind the click events. You can simply do

```
$('.entry .content .more-text').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.entry').find('.img-preview .expanded-image');
})
```